# UiPath says to check if robot service is started with InvalidOperationException

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

I have rebooted my computer and when I try and run my UiPath Sudio project that was working fine yesterday, I get a Runtime execution error saying Orchestrator information is not available and to check if the robot service is started.

[image]

Any idea why my RPA application isn’t working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say there are three possible reasons why your [UiPath Robot](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Create-your-first-RPA-robot-to-UiPath-Orchestrator-tutorial) isn't starting:

1. The Windows UiPath Robot Service hasn't started
2. UiPath Assistant is not connected to UiPath Orchestrator
3. You are running the program on a different machine

### UiPath Service

Windows configures the UiPath Robot service to initialize with a delayed start. If your computer has a large number of services, you may boot up Studio and run your UiPath App before it's actually initialized. In this case, you can solve the problem with patience and just wait. Or you can be more proactive and change the startup type to Automatic from Automatic(Delayed Start)

[image]

### UiPath Assistant

You may simply not have UiPath Assistant configured or running. In order to connect to or [publish to UiPath](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-configure-Assistant-and-publish-to-UiPath-Orchestrator) Orchestrator, the UiPath Assistant must be running. Check to make sure it's running and it's connected.

[image]

### Wrong computer?

You said you rebooted, so this may not be your problem. But I once did a git clone of a project on another computer and when I tried to run the app I couldn't connect to UiPath Orchestrator and couldn't figure out why because is worked on my other laptop.

Of course, every laptop needs its own unique machine configuration in [UiPath Orchestrator](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-create-a-UiPath-Orchestrator-process-to-run-your-RPA-robots). It was an obvious error but so obvious it took me a long time to figure it out. So just remember each machine needs its own UiPath Orchestrator configuration and UiPath Assistant connection.

Comment: It was the UiPath service not starting fast enough on reboot.